# Scrollable Grid in WPF/Silverlight

Tags: wpf, silverlight, grid, scrollviewer

I would like to build a WPF window which uses an **outer Grid** to split **the screen into 4 parts**. In the lower right quadrant, I would like to **embed another Grid which is larger than the grid cell**. I have been looking for ways to add a ScrollViewer (or use the Grid.ScrollViewer properties) but no matter what I try **the inner grid does not resize or display the scrollbars appropriately**.

I suspect it has something to do with **not wrapping the inner grid with the correct panel with the appropriate sizing (and resizing) behavior** which would force the inner grid to honor the scrollbars, instead of simply rendering too big (and being clipped by the other window).

The hosting window is defined like this:

```
<Window x:Class="GridScrollTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GridScrollTest"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid x:Name="OuterGrid">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="100" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <local:SSControl x:Name="Sheet" 
                         Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
                         HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Yellow" />
        <Canvas Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Background="LightGreen" />
        <Canvas Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Background="LightBlue" />
        <Canvas Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Background="LightCoral" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And the referenced SSControl:

```
<UserControl x:Class="GridScrollTest.SSControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    Height="270" Width="600">
    <ScrollViewer 
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
        CanContentScroll="True" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <Grid x:Name="CellGrid" ShowGridLines="False" 
              >
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"  />
                <RowDefinition Height="30"  />
                <RowDefinition Height="30"  />
                <RowDefinition Height="30"  />
                <RowDefinition Height="30"  />
                <RowDefinition Height="30"  />
                <RowDefinition Height="30"  />
                <RowDefinition Height="30"  />
                <RowDefinition Height="30"  />
                <RowDefinition Height="30"  />
                <RowDefinition Height="30"  />
                <RowDefinition Height="30"  />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: What exactly is your result? You say *"the inner grid does not resize or display the scrollbars appropriately"*, but from your explanation, I think you do not want it to resize, do you? My understanding of your description is that you want the Grid to be displayed in its actual size, across the boundaries of your Window, and that scroll bars are added to it, so that the user can scroll the viewable part. Is that right?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know for sure, but after trying your code in Blend, I think your problem might be that you have set the `ColumnDefinition.Width` and `RowDefinition.Height` to `Auto`. Try setting them to `*` and remove the `Height=270` and `Width=600` for your user control. This way, the outer grid fills all the available space in the window, and the lower right cell has scroll bars.

Comment: Changing the Width and Height definitions from Auto (which apparently means that whatever you need) to '*' (which seems to indicate the remaining space) solve the problem. Thx!

Comment: Yes, this is exactly their meaning. **Auto** means the content of the cell says how much space it needs and it typically gets that space. **Star-sized** means that the cell should take the remaining space. You can also make one column have `Width="1*"` and another one set to `Width="2*"` which means that the first column will take one third of the remaining space, and the second one the other two thirds. This feature is quite powerful when you need to provide a flexible layout in a resizable window.